# Altenative way to detect screen off/on

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, screen

Is there an alternative way to detect screen on/off in Android?
I'm currently using `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` intents catched with a receiver, but in API 17 it's [bugged](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41513&q=action_screen_off&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) (in combination with proximity wake lock).

Comment: It may be intentional, the proximity sensor is usually used while one app is running, so the screen on/off intents could be launching other apps that interfere with the app that should *currently* have focus.

Comment: This would be true if they didn't launch intents every time the proximity sensor is registered. But they only do this when the proximity wake lock is enabled.